# Upload files to google drive using Google.Apis.Drive.v3 in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-drive-api

I want to upload files to Google Drive using the Google.Apis.Drive.v3 in asp.net MVC. I want my visitor to upload the files to my google drive, I will set the credentials of my google drive in code. Can anyone help me to get this work?

I tried the quick start sample for upload but it asks for the credentials every time. Or it uses the cached credential.

How can I upload a file without knowing the user about the credential?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet), you need to get the access credentials to enable the Google Drive. If you want to programmatically access users data without any manual authorization on their part, then perform [Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#perform_google_apps_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority). To delegate authority this way, domain administrators can use service accounts with [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). You can also check on this [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) which might help.