# Google Drive API access from server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm able to upload files to google drive using Google.Apis.Drive.v3 in asp.net MVC but when I hosted to the server, it does not work, nor it gives me an error or exception.

I tried to log the executed steps and found out that it does not go or execute the below statement:

```
UserCredential credential1 = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        new ClientSecrets
                        {
                            ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

                            ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        },
                        new[] { Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

It works successfully locally. Can anyone say the cause of this or if I'm missing something?

Comment: What is the error or exception?

Comment: UserCredential are supposed to bring a UI to the end-user can consent and authorize. This can't work in a server. You need a service account: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload files to google drive using Google.Apis.Drive.v3 in asp.net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916260/upload-files-to-google-drive-using-google-apis-drive-v3-in-asp-net-mvc)